# How to start counting from 1 in lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, oop

I have created this board using lists. I want it to be numbered from 1 to 9 not from 0 to 8.

```
class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.boared = [' 'for _ in range(9)]
        self.currentWinner = None
        
    def printBoared(self):
        for row in [self.boared[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]:
            print('| '+' | '.join(row)+' |')
    @staticmethod
    def printBoaredNums():
        numberBoared =[[str(i) for i in range(j*3,(j+1)*3)] for j in range(3)]
        for row  in  numberBoared:
             print('|'+'|'.join(row)+'|')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you just have to change your ranges:

```
def printBoared(self):
    for row in [self.boared[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(1,4)]:
        print('| '+' | '.join(row)+' |')
@staticmethod
def printBoaredNums():
    numberBoared =[[str(i) for i in range(j*3,(j+1)*3)] for j in range(1,4)]
    for row  in  numberBoared:
         print('|'+'|'.join(row)+'|')
```